# ReactiveOpaqueTokenResolver with webflux ResourceServer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-security

I have my own OpaqueTokenResolver in Spring Boot (3.0.6). I'd like to make it reactive since I'm using webflux.

This works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
    @Autowired
    TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
        return tokenRepository.findItemByToken(token)
                .map(t -> new DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(t.user, Map.of("sub", t.user), Set.of())).block();
    }   
}
```

I thought I could make it reactive by implementing ReactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
    @Autowired
    TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    public Mono<OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal> introspect(String token) {
        return tokenRepository.findItemByToken(token)
                .map(t -> new DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(t.user, Map.of("sub", t.user), Set.of())).block();
    }   
}
```

but in the second case it cannot find an opaque token resolver. I'm guessing perhaps it is because I'm setting up HttpSecurity with:

```
@Configuration
class ContentSecurityPolicyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

that seems to be Servlet focused.

What is the correct way to do OpaqueTokenResolution with webflux?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that spring boot was not auto detecting the application type correctly. i had to add the following to my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE
```

now the following works:

```
@Configuration
class ContentSecurityPolicyConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    public Mono<OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal> introspect(String token) {
        return tokenRepository
                .findItemByToken(token)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BadOpaqueTokenException("unknown token")))
                .map(t -> new DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(t.user, Map.of("sub", t.user, "src", "oauth"),
                                                                  Set.of()));
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken().introspector(this::introspect);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: further investigation revealed that i was indirectly depending on spring-boot-starter-web which was messing things up.